# Printing QRImage In Detail Band without Hiding Image

Tags: delphi, report, quickreports

I am Having Problem Printing QRimage in detail band.
I need a floating QRImage which shall print in First page but not in second page

Answer (score 0):

if you use a new QRBand but only for put the QRimage?, because if QRBand don't increment so not shall show in the next page.